# I want to prevent the appearance of the cursor from changing between different applications

Tags: 22.04, cursor, cursor-theme

The appearance of the mouse cursor change from the default setting when I am in different applications. for e.g. -

1. In Clion. The cursor size decreases.
2. In mpv player. both size and appearance changes.

I want to prevent this override behaviour.

Comment: Only happens on electron apps or snap. Both ignore any theme changes. Which distro and version are you using?

Comment: ubuntu non-LTS 22.04

Comment: @kanehekili `Only happens on electron apps or snap`. In VS Code I don't get this problem (which is an electron app). And non of the above mentioned apps are made with electron. I don't get your point.

Comment: The 22.04 release *IS* LTS.

Comment: I get the same problem; CLion is using Bibata-Modern-Classic instead of the one I set in themes (DMZ White).  How do you stop this?